# Raspberry Pi to send sensor's data to server continuously and receive commands from server

Tags: communication, raspberry-pi, data-transfer

I would like to design a system using Raspberry Pi that sends the sensor's data to server continuously and receive commands from server.

Will MQTT suit my needs ?

Is there any way to do so if I use Java on my Pi?

**Edit**

By continuously I mean that streams like video are continuous and other text based data is sent twice every minute.

The sensors are:

Humidity sensor - http://www.amazon.in/DHT11-Temperature-Humidity-Sensor-Module/dp/B01HI9G9ZU?tag=googinhydr18418-21&tag=googinkenshoo-21&ascsubtag=710c9d6b-87d0-41e2-b3e0-06a1045769f3

A 5MP camera (Webcam connected to USB of the Pi.)

LDR(Light and Dark) - Sensor

The server is based on a cloud hosting location.

Comment: Thank you ;) I'd also like to know if you have choosen a specific cloud hosted server, important for the MQTT approach

Comment: @Goufalite no i simply have a cloud server machine at google cloud nothing fancy a simple cloud server with 4GB memory and 2 cores of compute power.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok here goes

- **Install MQTT on your Raspberry Pi**

Look if it is already running on your Rpi linux flavor or [install it](http://www.instructables.com/id/Installing-MQTT-BrokerMosquitto-on-Raspberry-Pi/)

- **Expose your MQTT port**

Look at which port MQTT is installed and open this port [using port forwarding](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/787/connect-to-device-at-home-network-remotely/792#792) with your broadband modem

- **Connect your cloud server to your local MQTT**
- **Test your sensors**

I don't know how the temperature sensor will be connected, my best guess would be with an Arduino. If it is the case, [you can connect it to MQTT with a shield](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/1190/how-to-use-mqtt-on-arduino-which-uses-serial-com-to-send-at-commands-to-esp8266). If not, please edit your question to tell us how your sensors will be connected to your system.

- **Monitor your camera**

Raspberry Pi has a library called [`motion`](http://www.techradar.com/how-to/computing/how-to-build-a-raspberry-pi-security-camera-1321441) which allows to control the camera, its behaviour on detection,...

Unless `motion` has already a MQTT interface, your best move is to output movements as pictures and then use a homemade service which uses [`inotify`](https://techarena51.com/blog/inotify-tools-example/) to wait for a new file and act (MQTT /camera/motion yes)

If you need more advice, please edit your question with other elements.

Answer (score 3):

> By continuously I mean that streams like video are continuous

If you are considering continuous video streaming from Pi then LIVE555 Streaming Media is a may serve your purpose. [Live555](http://www.live555.com/) will provide following:

- Source distribution for standards based RTP/RTCP/RTSP/SIP multimedia streaming
- Suitable for embedded and/or low-cost streaming application